# Проблема с созданием glFramebuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl

не могу создать буфер кадра в своем приложении для андроид на java. Пожалуйста, можете сказать, что я делаю не так. При попытке вызова glCheckFramebufferStatus выбивает статус 1. Этот статус не соответствует GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, но при этом и такого кода ошибки найти мне не удалось.
Здесь я создаю текстуру:

```java
public static int load(int width, int height) {
        int texture = MTexture.createTextures(1)[0];
        MTexture.bind(texture);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height,
                0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        MTexture.bind(0);

        return texture;
    }
```

А здесь уже буфер кадра:

```java
public static int load(int texture) {
        int framebuffer = createFramebuffers(1)[0];
        bind(framebuffer);

        MTexture.bind(texture);

        glFramebufferTexture2D(
                GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                texture,
                0);

        int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(framebuffer);
        if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            new MException("Framebuffer error. Status: " + status).printStackTrace(); //будет напечатано: 1

        bind(0);

        return framebuffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Так, я сам нашел проблему (искал несколько дней, написал на форум - нашел через минуту). Просто я в check передавал не тот аргумент. Нужно было указать target, а не объект. То есть GL_FRAMEBUFFER.